# Swift integration issue in Xcode 9?

Tags: ios11, swift4, xcode9, objc-bridging-header

I am working on an Application written in Swift. I added Objective-C classes. I have done every thing described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html), Now i can use all my Objective-C classes in Swift files but can't access Swift files in Objective-C classes. Even I can't import the file "MyProjectName-Swift.h" in my Objective-C class.

I have also done with the following settings:

**1: Define Modules:** YES

**2: Product Module Name:** (Make sure project module name does not contain any special character).

**3:Install Objective-C Compatibility Header:** YES

**4:Objective-C Generated Interface Header:** myProjectName-Swift.h

**5: Objective-C Bridging Header:** $(SRCROOT)/myProject-Bridging-Header.h

But no luck. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or something missing. your help and experience would be appreciated.